# Usage of XSLT Params; <xsl:param> & <xsl:with-param>

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Please explain me how best XSLT param can be used.
in terms of `<xsl:param>` & `<xsl:with-param>`

Sample LOC:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ABC">
    <xsl:with-param name="title" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. While I give a detailed explanation of `xsl:param` and `xsl:with-param` in my answer, I would recommend that you read a good book on XSLT. Practice is absolutely necessary in order to come with good grip of this concept.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Please explain me how best XSLT param can be used. in terms of
>   `<xsl:param>` & `<xsl:with-param>`

`<xsl:param>` can be specified at the global level anywhere (as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`) or if it is within a template, it must be its child and it must precede any non-`xsl:param` child of `xsl:template`.

This is the facility that allows a template or the whole transformation (in case of a global `xsl:param`) to receive varying data from the caller/initiator of the template or of the whole transformation, respectively.

On the side of the caller/initiator of the template/transformation, parameters are passed by using an `xsl:with-param` instruction. it can be a child of `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:call-template`.

The `name` attribute of either `xsl:param` or `xsl:with-param` is mandatory. It identifies the parameter.

The select attribute of `xsl:with-param` may be used to specify *any* XPath expression, the result of whose evaluation is passed to the called/applied template.

Alternatively, the value can be specified in the content (body) of `xsl:with-param`.

`xsl:with-param` must have either a `select` attribute or a body. but not both of them.

An `xsl:param` can also have a select attribute or body. In this case, these specify *the default value* of the parameter and it is used if no parameter with this name has been specified by the caller.

**Finally, here is a complete example illustrating most of these concepts**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pTarget" select="'love'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pReplacement" select="'like'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:call-template name="replace">
   <xsl:with-param name="pPattern" select="$pTarget"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pRep" select="$pReplacement"/>
  </xsl:call-template>

  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

  <xsl:call-template name="replace"/>

  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="text()">
   <xsl:with-param name="pPattern" select="$pTarget"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pRep" select="'adore'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="replace">
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
   <xsl:param name="pPattern" select="'hate'"/>
   <xsl:param name="pRep" select="'disapprove'"/>

   <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, $pPattern))">
          <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $pPattern)"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$pRep"/>

         <xsl:call-template name="replace">
           <xsl:with-param name="pPattern" select="$pPattern"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pRep" select="$pRep"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
            "substring-after($pText, $pPattern)"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document...**

```
<t>Sports stars we really love, love to hate, hate</t>
```

**...the result is...**

```
Sports stars we really like, like to hate, hate
Sports stars we really love, love to disapprove, disapprove
Sports stars we really adore, adore to hate, hate
```

**Explanation**:

1. The `replace` template is called twice. In both calls the `pText` parameter is omitted. Its default value is used by the called template.
2. The first call provides the pattern and replacement parameters, so `"love"` is replaced by `"like"`.
3. Do note that the values of the global parameters `$pTarget`  and `$pReplacement` are passed through. If the initiator of the transformation decides to pass other values (not the defaults that are used in this code) for these global parameters, these values will be passed to the `replace` template and not the defaults `"love"` and `"like"`.
4. The second call doesn't provide any parameter values at all, so all defaults in the `replace` template are used -- the string `"hate"` is replaced by the string `"disapprove"`.
5. Note that the `replace` template calls itself recursively, so that all occurrences of the pattern are replaced by the replacement.
6. Also, the values of the `pText` parameter of the recursive calls aren't static, but are dynamically calculated.
7. The third time the `replace` template is initiated from outside is via `xsl:apply-templates`. Here we also show that a template can have both a `match` and a `name` attribute at the same time and it is possible that such a template can be initiated both using `xsl:apply-templates` and `xsl:call-template`.

Comment: That's perfect answer Dimitre. Thanks for explaning the answer in more detailed way. I have small query, `<xsl:param>` & `<xsl:with-param>` should be used in between `<xsl:apply-templates>` & `<xsl:call-template>` or we can use either one. If yes, which is the best one between this two templates (`<xsl:apply-templates>` & `<xsl:call-template>`) & which is the more efficient one in using?

Comment: @Siva Charan: `xsl:param` is used only as a global parameter or as a child of `xsl:template` . With both `xsl:apply-templates` and `xsl:call-templates` the *only* way to specify passing of parameters is via `xsl:with-param`

Answer (score 10):

It's used to pass a param defined in another template:

```
<xsl:param name="globalParam"></xsl:param>

<xsl:call-template name="ABC">
  <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'A Title'" />
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="ABC">
  <xsl:param name="title"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$globalParam" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. **'A Title'** is a static value. right? if yes, can we pass a static value in XSLT. please explain some more info in detailed way...

Comment: The param can be a static value or a match expression. If you want to pass in a param define it in the outer scope. You can then set it when you preform the transform.

Comment: Actually, as shown in my answer, a template may pass an `xsl:param` *to itself* in a recursive call. Therefore the statement "It's used to pass a param defined in another template", isn't completely correct.

Comment: It's correct in the context of the question, I think that's being a bit picky on the wording