# pass <xsl:param> to <a href>

Tags: java, xslt, transform, href, transformer-model

I try to pass parameter

```
<xsl:param name="current_item" />
```

Before that I sent parameter as `transformer.setParameter("current_item", "Ball");`

But when I try to set this parameter as parameter

```
<a href="controller?command=transform&amp;current_item={$current_item}"></a>
```

In this row I get error  Variable or parameter 'current_item' is undefined.'
How I should specify this variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I resolved my problem by seting a global `<xsl:param>`.**

Before I had been using `<xsl:param>` in one from 2 `<xsl:template>` and tried to set in the href of another `<xsl:template>`.

**[Excerpt from an answer to a similar question about the Usage of XSLT Parameters:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7379232/14419)**

> `<xsl:param>` can be specified at the global level anywhere (as a
>   child of `xsl:stylesheet`) or if it is within a template, it must be
>   its child and it must precede any non-`xsl:param` child of
>   `xsl:template`.
>
> This is the facility that allows a template or the whole
>   transformation (in case of a global `xsl:param`) to receive varying
>   data from the caller/initiator of the template or of the whole
>   transformation, respectively.